# Where do sites get all the upcoming flights from?

Tags: data-request, aviation

There are various sites where we can search for various flights (opodo, flights.google.com and so on).

I think, these sites get some public, centralized aviation planning of all the upcoming (planned) flights of the world, and then they use various algorithms to present the best for us.

What are they using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's public, You can see all flights on https://www.flightradar24.com/

and you can get data from API's like:
https://rapidapi.com/collection/flightradar24-api

Comment: Does any of these APIs actually provide _open data_?